# Pandas Resampling with Groups and long-format time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

**Problem:** I have the following datastructure:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"time": ["2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00", "2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00", "2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00 ", "2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00", "2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00"],
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
    "other_text": ["desc1", "desc2", "desc3", "desc1", "desc2"],
    "value": [10, 30, 20, 90, 100]}
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The sampling frequency is 1-minute.
I would like to achieve that also id number 3 is shown with a forward filled value of 20 for "2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00" and so on.

I was thinking about grouping the data by time, id and other_text but I am not sure how I could get the additional row for id=3 and time="2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00" in it.

I would like to keep the long data format.

Any suggestions? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then forward filling missing values and last reshape back by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['time', 'id']).unstack().ffill().stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
print (df)
                        time  id other_text  value
0  2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00   1      desc1   10.0
1  2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00   2      desc2   30.0
2  2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00   3      desc3   20.0
3  2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00   1      desc1   90.0
4  2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00   2      desc2  100.0
5  2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00   3      desc3   20.0
```

If possible some datetimes not exist:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df = (df.set_index(['time', 'id'])
        .unstack()
        .ffill()
        .resample('Min')
        .ffill()
        .stack(dropna=False)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
                       time  id other_text  value
0 2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00   1      desc1   10.0
1 2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00   2      desc2   30.0
2 2021-01-10 23:09:00+00:00   3      desc3   20.0
3 2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00   1      desc1   90.0
4 2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00   2      desc2  100.0
5 2021-01-10 23:10:00+00:00   3      desc3   20.0
```